# Pandas Dataframe find intervals and count occurances

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I got a list of different events with mixed occurrences. For instance the event1 might occur three times, then another event and later on event1 will occur again.

What I need is the intervals for each event and the number of occurrences of that event in those intervals.

```
values = {
        '2017-11-28 11:00': 'event1',
        '2017-11-28 11:01': 'event1',
        '2017-11-28 11:02': 'event1',
        '2017-11-28 11:03': 'event2',
        '2017-11-28 11:04': 'event2',
        '2017-11-28 11:05': 'event1',
        '2017-11-28 11:06': 'event1',
        '2017-11-28 11:07': 'event1',
        '2017-11-28 11:08': 'event3',
        '2017-11-28 11:09': 'event3',
        '2017-11-28 11:10': 'event2',
        }

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(values, orient='index').reset_index()
df.columns = ['time', 'event']
df['time'] = df['time'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
df.set_index('time', inplace=True)
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
df.head()
```

The expected result is:

```
occurrences = [
        {'start':'2017-11-28 11:00',
         'end':'2017-11-28 11:02',
         'event':'event1',
         'count':3},
        {'start':'2017-11-28 11:03',
         'end':'2017-11-28 11:04',
         'event':'event2',
         'count':2},
        {'start':'2017-11-28 11:05',
         'end':'2017-11-28 11:07',
         'event':'event1',
         'count':3},
        {'start':'2017-11-28 11:08',
         'end':'2017-11-28 11:09',
         'event':'event3',
         'count':2},
        {'start':'2017-11-28 11:10',
         'end':'2017-11-28 11:10',
         'event':'event2',
         'count':1},
        ]
```

I was thinking to use **pd.merge_asof** to find the start/end times of the intervals and the use **pd.cut** ([as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010215/pandas-groupby-how-to-compute-counts-in-ranges)) for **groupby and count**. But somehow I'm stuck. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: are you only looking got pandas based solution? You can iterate over it, for non pandas based solution.

Comment: I bet that there is a nice Pandas solution. I found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26539646/python-pandas-count-interval-of-occurrence) that is based on iteration. But Pandas would be preferable.

Comment: You may even look at here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25119524/pandas-conditional-rolling-count ,

Comment: @VivekHarikrishnan very nice idea. Good starting point. The problem remains how to group them by the intervals - meaning how do you know when the **highest cumcount** for an interval has been reached? PS: I found a solution. If you post yours, I will accept it. Otherwise I'll post mine.

Comment: Based on @chrisb's answer in the question @Vivek Harkrishnan mentioned, you could do `groupby` on `block` then choose `min('time')` as `start` and `max('time')` as `end`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following approach:

```
In [68]: x = df.reset_index()

In [69]: (x.groupby(x.event.ne(x.event.shift()).cumsum())
    ...:   .apply(lambda x:
    ...:             pd.DataFrame({
    ...:                 'start':[x['time'].min()],
    ...:                 'end':[x['time'].min()],
    ...:                 'event':[x['event'].iloc[0]],
    ...:                 'count':[len(x)]})
    ...:         )
    ...:   .reset_index(drop=True)
    ...:   .to_dict('r')
    ...: )
Out[69]:
[{'count': 3,
  'end': Timestamp('2017-11-28 11:00:00'),
  'event': 'event1',
  'start': Timestamp('2017-11-28 11:00:00')},
 {'count': 2,
  'end': Timestamp('2017-11-28 11:03:00'),
  'event': 'event2',
  'start': Timestamp('2017-11-28 11:03:00')},
 {'count': 3,
  'end': Timestamp('2017-11-28 11:05:00'),
  'event': 'event1',
  'start': Timestamp('2017-11-28 11:05:00')},
 {'count': 2,
  'end': Timestamp('2017-11-28 11:08:00'),
  'event': 'event3',
  'start': Timestamp('2017-11-28 11:08:00')},
 {'count': 1,
  'end': Timestamp('2017-11-28 11:10:00'),
  'event': 'event2',
  'start': Timestamp('2017-11-28 11:10:00')}]
```

or the following if you want to have `time` column as strings:

```
In [75]: (x.groupby(x.event.ne(x.event.shift()).cumsum())
    ...:   .apply(lambda x:
    ...:             pd.DataFrame({
    ...:                 'start':[x['time'].min().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')],
    ...:                 'end':[x['time'].min().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')],
    ...:                 'event':[x['event'].iloc[0]],
    ...:                 'count':[len(x)]})
    ...:         )
    ...:   .reset_index(drop=True)
    ...:   .to_dict('r')
    ...: )
Out[75]:
[{'count': 3,
  'end': '2017-11-28 11:00:00',
  'event': 'event1',
  'start': '2017-11-28 11:00:00'},
 {'count': 2,
  'end': '2017-11-28 11:03:00',
  'event': 'event2',
  'start': '2017-11-28 11:03:00'},
 {'count': 3,
  'end': '2017-11-28 11:05:00',
  'event': 'event1',
  'start': '2017-11-28 11:05:00'},
 {'count': 2,
  'end': '2017-11-28 11:08:00',
  'event': 'event3',
  'start': '2017-11-28 11:08:00'},
 {'count': 1,
  'end': '2017-11-28 11:10:00',
  'event': 'event2',
  'start': '2017-11-28 11:10:00'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two solutions. The first one is based on the link provided by [vivek-harikrishnan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2963886/vivek-harikrishnan) and [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25119524/pandas-conditional-rolling-count). It creates continuous numbers for the intervals and cumulatively counts the occurrences within such intervals.

```
#%% first solution

# create intervals and count occurrences per interval
df['interval'] = (df['event'] != df['event'].shift(1)).astype(int).cumsum()
df['count'] = df.groupby(['event', 'interval']).cumcount() + 1

# now group by intervals
df.groupby('interval').last()
```

The second solution is based on the answer above given by [maxu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5741205/maxu). Similar to the first idea it also creates interval numbers but also finds the start/end timestamp for such intervals.

```
#%% second solution

df = df.reset_index()
# create intervals
df = df.groupby(df['event'].ne(df['event'].shift()).cumsum())
# calc start/end times and count occurances at the same time
df.apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame({
                    'start':[x['time'].min()], 
                    'end':[x['time'].max()],
                    'event':[x['event'].iloc[0]],
                    'count':[len(x)]})).reset_index(drop=True)
```